# Pusher connection not working on physical Android device, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

I am using [pusher_client 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_client) to connect to [Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/) which is hosted on my VPS and replaces paid Pusher.
When the application is run on the Android Emulator, or on a physical device in debug mode, everything works fine. The data is coming in, there is a connection to the Websockets server.
But if you compile the application (flutter build apk) and run this apk on a physical device, then the connection with Laravel Websockets does not work. However, normal HTTP requests are sent without problems.

The `AndroidManifest` contains the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. I also tried to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest`. And tried to allow [Insecure HTTP connections](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android) through the `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml` file.

Contents of [AndroidManifest.xml](https://pastebin.com/MzXmUe20)

Contents of [network_security_config.xml](https://pastebin.com/X34fhXYa)